# Cannot insert a data in SQLite using ios

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, insert, xcode4.5

I use this code and always says "Error añadir contacto" is the same as "Error adding the contact", what's wrong? My DB is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacto (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, direccion TEXT, telefono TEXT)
```

My code is:

```
-(IBAction)addContacto
{
    const char *dbpath = [_rutaDB UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Contacto (nombre, direccion, telefono) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",_nomb.text,_dir.text,_tlf.text];
        const char *insert_stmt = [consulta UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            _status.text = @"Contacto añadido.";
            _status.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            _status.text = @"Error añadir contacto.";
            _status.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_db);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

PD: the table created is ok, and I inserted a default entry and works:

```
                const char *sql_insert = "INSERT INTO Contacto (nombre, direccion, telefono) VALUES ('Pepe', 'Avila 34', '928776622')";
            sqlite3_exec(_db,sql_insert, NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

Only executed when DB is created.

Thanks again.

Comment: Change this line _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"Error  añadir contacto.  '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_db)]; Let me know what you get in log

Comment: please NSLog the `consulta` and check the query. Also check `if(qlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)`

Comment: Let me see:

@Prateek: Your error says -> no such table: Contacto
-Midhun MP: the NSLog says -> Consulta: INSERT INTO Contacto (nombre, direccion, telefono) VALUES ("Louis","Pilla 82","928776651")

Comment: @rokimoki Its simple, you dont have table Contacto exists. If you have created this table recently, you need to delete your application and re-run it. Let me know if your issue gets solved..

Comment: @Prateek My error was simple, addContacto was in other viewController, so in that view controller I didn't open/calculate the patch to my "contactos.db", so that's why Contacto was not found... Noob mistake, I'm new to iOS and it's so weird that language, thanks and sorry to disturb.

Comment: @rokimoki Never mind and happy icoding.. :)

Comment: In general (I'm sure there are exceptions), you should initialize your DB in the app delegate, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.  That way it's available to every part of the application.